# Excel : long calculus vs lot of tables ?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, google-spreadsheets

I haven't got any problem, but I ask myself a question. In my current project, I use a lot of formulae and I group them into few cells. So I use very few tables and very few simple formulas but each table and each formula could be cut into simpler forms.

My question is : what's the best optimization / the best way to do your sheets if you have the absolute liberty ? Create a lot of tables with simple operations into them (even if you create extra sheets for it) or regroup multiple formulas in one if you have the possibility to do it ?

So basically my question could be : few cells, few tables with complex formulas or lot of cells and tables with the simplest formulas than you can ?

Thanks a lot for your help !

Comment: This totally depends on the specifics.  There is no general answer.  You would have to provide examples of the formulas you're using now and how you would do the alternative.  Then you would have to define optimization (least memory use? fastest recalculation? ease of maintenance or expansion? etc.)

Comment: It should be 1. error avoidance (if I do a mistake, I should spot it quickly) and 2. elegance (clean and organized).